# How to insert an inline image from URL in Hotmail and Yahoo

Tags: outlook.com, yahoo-mail

How do you add an inline image from a URL in Hotmail and Yahoo?

Gmail allows it simply by: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/148408

Answer (score 1):

On Hotmail you do image linking, you have to have the image on some site to be able to link it on Hotmail.

For example this image:

```
http://cdn.sstatic.net/superuser/img/it-kama-sutra.jpg
```

You open it on your browser then you go to `Edit > Select ALL` then `Edit > Copy`, using the mouse did not work for me on Firefox.

Then on Hotmail at the compose message page you click on the message body and press either `Ctrl+V` or `Edit > Paste`

And it works just fine.

There is also this video that shows how to do it on Hotmail, Yahoo and Gmail:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gokROfGPEgo
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Google Chrome browser for Hotmail. Open new email and select picture inline option from Insert menu next to send menu. Select the picture file to upload as inline. You can see the picture attached as inline.